# users cannot be redirected to website from facebook advertisement

Tags: facebook, ads

We publish advertisement on facebook and we have a new domain. The problem is that advertisement click rate on facebook panel is 6193 but only 1682 person enter website accordşng to google analytic.

There are about 4500 hit which is lost. AS you know, users are redirected to our website after click on facebook advertisement but they cannot access to our website. we are waiting your kindly response.

our website: testmastersatinal.com

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google's [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?rd=2) to properly code the landing page URL in such a way that GA will recognize the traffic as having come from your FB advertising campaign.  Here's a [blog](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/01/16/tracking-facebook-ads-with-google-analytics/) describing how it is done.

For reasons that I do not yet completely understand - but apparently have to do with the internal FB redirect process for ads, much of my traffic from Facebook shows up in Google Analytics as (direct)/(none).  I've found that setting the GA UTM codes on the landing page URL will help by using Google's [URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?rd=2) helps with this issue.

More generally, in my experience, advertiser reported clicks are often different from what you see in GA.  In fact, I'm working on trying to resolve this issue now with another advertising platform (not FB) who is billing us for 2.5x the number of clicks we are seeing in Google Analytics.

There are many possible causes for this, and you can find relevant discussions on
[webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57906/less-than-half-of-facebook-ad-clicks-are-visible-in-google-analytics), [moz](http://moz.com/community/q/facebook-ppc-number-of-clicks-according-to-fb-different-than-visits-in-analytics).

One thing you should try is segmenting the referrals by device (mobile, tablet, desktop) or operating system, etc.  See if the percentage of traffic is much lower from your ad on one particular device or operating system.  This may indicate that the GA tracking is not working correctly on that device or OS.

Comment: It looks a reasonable solution. I will try it and inform you.thanks